# Removing jQuery event from #id after clicking on it (or prevent a second click)

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

guys!

I am really doing my best to solve the problem below, but after many hours I am not able to see the correct path to go! Let me explain:

- I have a element a-href (#opener) that, when clicked, fires a jQueryUI modal dialog who loads through ajax a URL inside a div (#target).
- Everything works perfect, but I want this to happen once!
- After loading the modal window I was able to set a class (.deactivated) to my #opener a-href and to remove the id (#opener) to prevent the action to be fired again, however it does not work... the a-href remains clickable and opening the modal window (#target) as many times as I click on it!
- The only solution I found was to remove the a-href completely from the DOM --- using $(this).fadeOut(); ---, but it is really ugly, since my link #opener just vanishes in thin air.

Any ideas?
Thank yo sooo much.
G.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#opener').click (function() {

        $('#target').load ('http://my.url', function(){
            $('#target').dialog({
                title: 'My Title',
                draggable: true,
                dialogClass:'My Class',
                modal: true,
                hide: { effect: 'fade', speed: 'fast' },
                show: { effect: 'fade', speed: 'fast' },
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeText: 'Close',
                beforeClose: function(event, ui) { 
                   'window.location.reload(true)'
                },
            });//end dialog   
        });
        $(this).addClass('.deactivated');
        $(this).removeAttr('id');
    });
});
```

Comment: rule: save for possible re-use - utilize `on/off`; use ONLY one time and never again - utilize `one` function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing the ID from the element doesn't remove any handlers bound on that element (unless you had used "event delegation").

Either bind on the click event using [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (instead of `.on` or the obsolete `.bind`) which then automatically unbinds the handler after it fires the first time:

```
$('#opener').one('click', ...)
```

Or disable the event within the click handler:

```
$('#opener').on('click', function() {
    ...
    $(this).off('click').addClass('.deactivated');
});
```

NB: it's good practise to always use the newer `.on` (or `.one`) and `.off` functions instead of `.bind`, or `.click`, etc.  It makes event handling code more consistent and avoids confusion with how `.click` can be used to both *register* an event handler or (without parameters) *trigger* the event handlers.

Comment: Dear Alnitak! Thank you so much for such detailed help. Problem solved down here! I work with PHP and I am starting jQuery, and your help was very instructional. Best regards!

Comment: You can also set the deactivated inside the `one` if that is desired

Comment: hello, but how to reactivate button again? for example when click another element #opener will be activate to click again?

Answer (score 4):

**Description**

> .one(), Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is
>   executed at most once per element.

```
$('#opener').one('click',function(){
     //your code
    });
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! I feel ashamed for not finding a so obvious answer by myself...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function to set up an event handler that will only fire a single time, and then remove itself:

```
$('#opener').one('click', function(event) {
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `one`:

```
$('#opener').one("click", function() {

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/